# Shift a byte (number) by the decimal part of a division

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary

I am trying to shift an array of bytes based on the decimal part of `b / n`

The (simplified) formula I am using is (given `n = 2`):

```
b = b / 2
if (decimal part of b == 0.5) {
    b = floor(b) + 256 / 2
}
```

So in this case for:

```
b = 0 then 0
b = 1 then 128
b = 2 then 2
b = 3 then 129
```

It works fine until I get to `n = 6`, and I am unsure how to fix it.

Here is a full example: http://jsfiddle.net/cBY2H/4/embedded/result,js/

You can see in the console output:

```
Shift by 2-5: fine

Shift by 6: 
Extra 128
Missing 213

Shift by 7:
Extra 110
Missing 219

Shift by 8: fine
```

How can I make it work for at least `n = 2-9` and even better `n = 2+`?

***Actual code to do the shifting:***

```
function shiftByte(byte, shiftAmount) {
    var shiftSize = 256 / shiftAmount,
        decimal = 1 / shiftAmount,
        currentDecimal = decimal,
        shiftCount = 1;
    byte = byte / shiftAmount;
    while (numberLessThan(currentDecimal, 1)) {
        if (numberEquals(byte - Math.floor(byte), currentDecimal)) {
            return Math.ceil(shiftSize * shiftCount) + Math.floor(byte);
        }
        currentDecimal += decimal;
        shiftCount++;
    }
    return Math.floor(byte);
}
```

Comment: Maybe your numberEquals() function is returning false sometimes due to decimal resolution.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal `numberEquals` is pretty much `==` but with a `0.000001` tolerance to cater for floating point precision. The source of that function is in the JS Fiddle: `(a + tolerance) >= b && (a - tolerance) <= b`.

Comment: Is this a typo: `b = 2 then 2`? I would expect 1, or I don't understand the example.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to fill the array with unique indices, you could use a straightforward approach without all these fiddly floating-point divisions and comparisons:

```
function shiftData(data, n) {
    var result = [];
    var k = 0;
    var next = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result[k] = i;
        k += n;
        if (k > 256) {
            k = ++next;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This fills your byte field and also satisfies your validation routine.

If you need to call `shiftByte` outside `shiftData`, you can use the same approach and create the shifted table on the fly. You don't have to do that every time, of course: Keep a global dictionary with your shift amount (or possibly the shift amount and the table size) as key and the byte table as value. Create a table if it doesn't exist and just look up the bytes after that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you could benefit from a much simpler and direct formula, which would be both faster and prevents the nasty floating point arithmetic.

If I understand correctly, you categorise the bytes by modular index. That is:

```
var group = b % n;
```

Now you need to find the starting index of that group. That's easy if `n` divides 256, but a little more cumbersome otherwise. There are `256 % n` groups that contain 1 element more than the others. (See how that nicely degenerates  if `256 | n`.) The starting index for the group thus becomes:

```
var groupSize = Math.floor(256 / n);
var numberOfBiggerGroups = 256 % n;
var groupIndex = group * groupSize + max(group, numberOfBiggerGroups);
```

If I understand your algorithm correctly, the index in the group is determined by `Math.floor(b / n)`.

This leads to the following full method:

```
function shiftByte(b, n) {
    var group = b % n;
    var groupSize = Math.floor(256 / n);
    var groupIndex = group * groupSize  + Math.max(group, 256 % n);
    return groupIndex + Math.floor(b / n);
}
```